# JavaFX MediaPlayer unable to play local m3u8 file

Tags: ffmpeg, javafx-8, gstreamer, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I want to show a live stream of a web cam in my JavaFX application using the MediaPlayer/MediaView. My attempt was to use ffmpeg to record a HLS and to play the resulting m3u8 file, but that throws the following exception (VLC plays the video without problems):

```
MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:511)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:414)
    at de.fraunhofer.iosb.ias.flow.assessment.management.monitor.MonitorViewController.testStream(MonitorViewController.java:203)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:274)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:467)
    ... 60 more
```

I debugged the player creation and the error occurs inside the constructor of GSTMediaPlayer when `GSTMediaPlayer.gstInitPlayer()` is called. This native method returns  the error code `257`, which javafx maps to `MediaError.ERROR_MEDIA_NULL`.

I used the following ffmpeg command to record the video:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -rtbufsize 250MB -f dshow -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 960x720 -i video="Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.m3u8
```

I'm pretty sure that the encoding matches the [requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) of javafx, because if I change the output container from m3u8 to mp4, the video is played without problems using the exact same ffmpeg command.

This is the output of ffprobe for the m3u8 file:

```
Input #0, hls,applehttp, from 'out.m3u8':
  Duration: 00:00:24.23, start: 1.466667, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Program 0
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 960x720, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
```

And for the mp4 file:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
  Duration: 00:01:04.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1676 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x720, 1673 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

The resulting m3u8 file looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:9
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:8.333322,
out0.ts
#EXTINF:8.333333,
out1.ts
#EXTINF:7.133322,
out2.ts
#EXTINF:0.433333,
out3.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

**Update:** After I found [this](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/JavaRap/prog_index.m3u8) reference m3u file, I think that the problem is that the file is stored locally and isn't delivered via HTTP. The video plays fine with this:

```
Media media = new Media("http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/JavaRap/prog_index.m3u8");
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
player.setAutoPlay(true);
mediaView.setMediaPlayer(player);
```

But after I downloaded the reference m3u and all of its segments and tried to open the local file like this, the error occurred again:

```
File video = new File("H://Projects//Tools//ref//prog_index.m3u8");
Media media = new Media(video.toURI().toString());
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
player.setAutoPlay(true);
mediaView.setMediaPlayer(player);
```

I tried to change my m3u file so that the segements are referenced with absolute paths. I tried different notations (`H:\f\out0.ts`, `H:/f/out0.ts`, `H://f//out0.ts`, `file:/H:/f/out0.ts`, `file:///H:/f/out0.ts`), but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: What's in your m3u8 file? Could it be that your Java program can't find the segments?

Comment: Totally forgot to add the files content. I updated the question. But I don't think that the files content is the problem, since VLC can play it without problems.

Comment: 'VLC can play it without problems' is not that useful to you, though, since VLC will play a lot of things without problems. Try fiddling with your m3u some, say, use absolute paths or file urls. Can you get _any_ m3u to work? etc.

Comment: I tried to fiddle with the m3u, but I wasn't able to get it to work. But I was able to find a reference m3u that plays fine, when it's referenced via http but it doesn't play the local file after I downloaded it (and all the segments). I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Hello, Did you find the solution to play the local m3u8 videos, I need it for my application where the m3u8 videos are placed in local folder to play the videos. Could you please share code to play local m3u8 videos

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it seems like you're out of luck here. This is the relevant bit of logic from the bowels of the JDK:

in `com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator`

```
public ConnectionHolder createConnectionHolder() throws IOException {
    // [...] cache lookup elided
    ConnectionHolder holder;
    if ("file".equals(scheme)) {
        holder = ConnectionHolder.createFileConnectionHolder(uri);
    } else if (uri.toString().endsWith(".m3u8") || uri.toString().endsWith(".m3u")) {
        holder = ConnectionHolder.createHLSConnectionHolder(uri);
    }
```

As you can see, the first check is for a `file` scheme, at that point you get unceremoniously sent to the logic that handles actual media files. HLS playlist handling is triggered by a later check for file extension `.m3u8` but by that point it's too late, your local file has matched the previous condition and sent to the wrong place. You could argue this is a bug and file it as such, although it is a bit of an edge-case.

Comment: "You could argue this is a bug" Is there any way that a playlist could _actually_ be played? Doesn't seem so to me, so it defies its functionality. Nothing to argue, definitely a bug.

Comment: @Xerus If you're going to argue there is nothing to argue about on a site made up almost entirely of nerd arguments, you might, arguably, be in for a bit of a surprise :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with *WebEngine* accessing the local file system [file://].
And here is how it happens.

```
//Started app [run-able .jar] and loaded a start page [resource in .jar] 
protected static String Some_Resource_in_a_JAR = "/jimmylandstudios/gui/index.html";
webEngine.load(getClass()
.getResource(" + Some_Resource_in_a_JAR + ")
.toExternalForm());
//So, you can forget using the file:// protocol now.
```

My Answer has been either:
Use a *HTTP: server* for any created/modified files.
Or better,

```
//Avoid issue [accessing local files] 
protected static String Extracted_Resource_from_JAR = "/jimmylandstudios/gui/index.html";
webEngine.load("file://" + Extracted_Resource_from_JAR + ");
```

Simply put: ***Start WebEngine with the file:// protocol*** if your accessing Local files.